# How can I tell someone what I'm reading about?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

I was reading a book, and someone asked me, "¿Qué estás leyendo?"

I answered, "Estoy leyendo *sobre* ..."

The person looked at me funny, but seemed to understand what I said.

Looking back, it makes sense that *sobre* was the wrong choice.

What is the correct way to say *about* as a non-physical preposition?

Comment: I know this problem but I think the other good preposition to try when in doubt is always *de*.

Comment: Sobre is good too, but really depends on the country. In colombia they won't look at you funny :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Estoy leyendo *acerca de* ...

Comment: Does that translate literally to "about"?

Comment: Yes: http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=acerca%20de

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *sobre* you can use it this way:

> Estoy leyendo un libro **sobre** ...

Which means:

> I am reading a book **about** ...

Of course you can use it for magazines, an article, etc.